# Error SIGABRT na UITableView

Tags: ios, swift

O código abaixo compila mas depois apresenta o erro `12main SIGABRT` no `appdelegate.swift`, o que fazer? E a `tableview` ja esta ligada com data source e delegate a `viewcontroller`.

> 2016-01-09 16:34:54.433 Tabelas[17730:805874] *** Terminating app due
>   to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
>   'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle
>   
>   (loaded)' with name 'Main''

Arquivo viewcontroller.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {



    var cellContent = ["Ana, Lucia, Maria, Ja"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        }

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cellContent.count
        }

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

        cell.textLabel?.text = cellContent[indexPath.row]

        return cell
        }


        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Esse erro geralmente pode ocorrer por 2 motivos:

- Verifique se seu storyboard está adicionado no seu `Copy Bundle Resources`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Verifique se nas propriedades do seu `.storyboard` ou `.xib` está linkado com o target do seu projeto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]